# Is there any way to create a custom signature while signing the document?

Tags: docusignapi

How can i create a custom signature it is the user can upload is signature in any format like jpg,png etc while he is signing our document?

I saw this can be done by account my preferences settings of upload signature in docusign . But i want to add this feature in docusign integration using rest apis in our application?

can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. A user can always create a custom signature (can create via digital pen like s-pen ). What do you want to do ?

Comment: Yeah, i want that is user can upload is signature which is in format like jpg or png from is system while doing the signature .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Go to Admin > Signing Settings > Signature Adoption Configuration, there's an option to Disable Upload Signature, as well as set the default panel the signer sees. As long as Disable Upload Signature is unchecked, a signer will have the option to upload an image as their signature.

If you don't have access to Signature Adoption Configuration, reach out to your Account Manager to request that be enabled. 
If this is in the Demo environment, you can open a case with DocuSign Support requesting it be enabled. Be sure to include both your Production and Demo account IDs if you do.